# Checking for two separate things in an sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a friend relationship query. I want the following query to do two things, rather than making another very similar query.

I am wanting to check for pending requests and sent requests. Pending requests are when the user is friend_two. Sent requests are when friend_one is the user_id.

So, is there anyway I can adjust my where clause to something like this (I do not know how to write this out in SQL) -

```
WHERE friend_one = ? As pending_user
WHERE friend_two = ? AS sent_user
```

I am not sure if `AS`can be added to a where clause. The thing about the code I just wrote above is that the placeholder value will be the same value and I am not sure how I could write that in the php.

Right now, if I have the same user in the friend_one and friend_two column it counts all of the occurences of the user's occurence ie: if user #2 has his id in the friend_one column only 2 times, but has his id comes up in the friend_two column 8 times, the query will count 10 because of m,y where clause. I need the values to be 2 and 8.

How can I do this? See code and table below.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(friend_one) AS pending_count , COUNT(friend_two) AS requests_sent   
FROM friends
WHERE friend_one OR friend_two = ?
AND status = ?
```

friends table

```
Table
Create Table
friends
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `friend_one` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `friend_two` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `status` enum('0','1','2') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0',
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `friend_two` (`friend_two`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Square = requests_sent

Circle = pending_count

[image]

Comment: Why do you need `friend_one` and `friend_two` in where clause as `WHERE friend_one OR friend_two = ?` ???

Comment: If you are referring to this that I wrote in my question? `WHERE friend_one = ? As pending_user
WHERE friend_two = ? AS sent_user` I am not sure how to write what I am wanting, I just put that in for others to gain clarity.

Comment: Simply provide sample data and your expected result.

Comment: @viki888 Here you go. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e20472/1 ... I want `AS pending_count` to come up with the count 2 if `friend_one = ?` (the placeholder would be user_id 5) and then for the `As requests_sent` the value should be 1 (again if the user_id/placeholder is 5).

Comment: And how `requests_sent` should be 1?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't update: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/732d1b

Comment: Actually, `pending_count` should be 1 and `requests send = 2`. friend_one is the user sending the friend request. friend_two is the one receiving it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128464/discussion-between-viki888-and-paul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `@name, @status` parameters. I belive you want something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN `friend_one` = @name THEN 1 END) as `pending_count`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN `friend_two` = @name THEN 1 END) as `requests_count`
FROM friends
WHERE @name IN ( `friend_one` , `friend_two` )
  AND `status` = @status
```

Comment: This didn't work. I tried it out how you wrote it and after that didn't work I adjusted this section `WHERE @name IN ( ?)` and `AND `status` = ?` .... No luck there though. I also need to include the SELECT * as well.

Comment: well that code work ok in MySql. And you cant put * on this query because you need a `group by` . I guess you are new in sql, you have to write a better question explaining what you have and what you need. Show us sample data of both.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Here you go. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e20472/1 ... I want `AS pending_count` to come up with the count 2 if `friend_one = ?` (the placeholder would be user_id 5) and then for the `As requests_sent` the value should be 1 (again if the user_id/placeholder is 5).

Comment: Actually, pending_count should be 1 and requests send = 2. friend_one is the user sending the friend request. friend_two is the one receiving it

Comment: so what result you need? and what parameter you will send?

Comment: I want to use the same parameter for friend one and two. Then a parameter for status. The parameter for status will be 1 (which indicates a pending friend request). The friend 1/2 parameter will be the user_id that I have in my php.

For the example I made, check for user 5. (numbers in the friend 1 and 2) are user ids.

Comment: so `@user_id=5` and `@status=1`? and what would be the result?

Comment: If user_id is 5 and status 1, the results would be AS pending_requests = 1 ... requests_sent 2.

Comment: only those two fields? try to be precise, dont make me do something and then said you need something else

Comment: What are you talking about? I have simply told you what the parameters would be, what I want has always been the same.

Comment: I ask what result you want with those parameter. Still not clear for me

Comment: if friend_one = ? ....... ? = user_id.... which in this example, I am using 5. requests_sent would be 2. .......................... if friend_two = ?.....? = user_id....still using 5, the pending_count would be 1. Pending_count and requests_sent are the `AS` values I included above.

Comment: I just added an image to my question to help illustrate it.

Comment: So result would be `pending_count, request_sent` nothing else?

Comment: In my original query I am selecting *, which ideally, I would still like to do, if possible. But I need the `COUNT` figures as well

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand how I can set parameters with the user_id being used in so many places though. How would I set the parameters for that? I have the parameters in my execute statement `$pending_friend_count_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $status_one));`

Comment: that maybe is better to another question. Im not familiar with php. But at least now you have something to show your problem very clear ;)

Comment: I appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Am I able to `SELECT *` with this too?

Comment: No, because you are using an aggregated function. For example you have different `id,date` which one would you show? That is why I ask what result you want

Comment: Well, ideally I would like to include the date as well.

Comment: again, you can include date, but which one? the last one? http://rextester.com/FMDZD82742